# How is it that this Python code works correctly?

Tags: python, dictionary

This piece of Python code prints out the maximum age in the Age = {age:numberOfOccurence} dictionary. But because all the ages are already greater than zero, why does the code print out 50 as the maximum age?

```
Age = {45:3, 50:2, 25:1, 10:5, 15:10}
Oldest = 0

for MaxAge in Age:
    if MaxAge>Oldest:
        Oldest = MaxAge

print(Oldest)
```

Comment: why is it confusing?

Comment: I'd suggest to stick to the official naming conventions (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45). Age -> age, Oldest -> oldest, etc

Answer (score 2):

I commented the code and added some print statements to help you understand how it works.

```
Age = {45:3, 50:2, 25:1, 10:5, 15:10}
Oldest = 0 ## Initialize oldest with the minimum number

print('Initial Oldest Value: ', Oldest)

for MaxAge in Age: ## Iterating Age
    ## If age at current index is greater than oldest (which is 0 for first iteration)  
    if MaxAge>Oldest: 
        ## Update oldest with current age
        print('MaxAge: ', MaxAge, ' > Oldest: ', Oldest)
        Oldest = MaxAge
        print('New Oldest Value: ', Oldest)
        print('-'*10)


print('Final Oldest Value: ', Oldest)
```

**Output**

```
Initial Oldest Value:  0                                                                                                         
MaxAge:  25  > Oldest:  0                                                                                                        
New Oldest Value:  25                                                                                                            
----------                                                                                                                       
MaxAge:  50  > Oldest:  25                                                                                                       
New Oldest Value:  50                                                                                                            
----------                                                                                                                       
Final Oldest Value:  50
```

Answer (score 1):

Because, every-time something is greater than zero, you make the code set the `Oldest` variable to that, then next is greater than previous, that will be assigned, and so on... all this are done from this if statement:

```
if MaxAge>Oldest:
    Oldest = MaxAge
```

If you take out that, and add something else for the for loop, it won't work as expected.

Note that @andreihondrari's comment.

Comment: Eureka!

Thanks!

Comment: @CoolC Happy to help, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @CoolC Now you can :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are expecting the code to do something else, or if it's that you don't understand why it works.

However, you could take a look at this question and answer: [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

The reason the code works is that the for loop over a dictionary will iterate over the keys of the dictionary. You can see this if you add an extra print statement like this:

```
Age = {45:3, 50:2, 25:1, 10:5, 15:10}
Oldest = 0

for MaxAge in Age:
    print(MaxAge)
    if MaxAge>Oldest:
        Oldest = MaxAge

print(Oldest)
```

Then you should see:

```
45
50
25
10
15
50
```